# Cannot adjust layout when softkeyboard is up properly

Tags: android, layout, android-softkeyboard

i've a problem with my android layout. Basically i've added in the manifest the following line

```
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

And this is my layout :

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <####.TitleBar
            android:id="@+id/title_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:barLeftButton="false"
            app:barRightButton="true"
            app:barTitle="?attr/titleBarContactUs"
            app:overrideBackground="#0C2938"
            app:overridePaddingLeft="10dp"
            app:overridePaddingRight="10dp"
            />

        <####..AdaptableFontTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Come possiamo aiutarti?"
            android:textColor="#0C2938"
            android:textSize="26dp">

        </####..AdaptableFontTextView>

        <android.support.v4.widget.Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />

        <####..AdaptableFontTextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="@string/contact_us_description"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="#0C2938"
            android:textSize="?attr/contactUsFontSize">

        </####..AdaptableFontTextView>

        <android.support.v4.widget.Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp" />


        <Spinner
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/contact_us_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeSpinner"
            android:minHeight="40dp"
            android:minWidth="300dp"/>

        <android.support.v4.widget.Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/contactUsUserText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight = "1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/ksw_md_ripple_normal"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:hint="@string/begin_fragmetn_input_hint"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textSize="?attr/highContrastBeginText"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"

            />

        <android.support.v4.widget.Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ContactUsSendEmail"
            android:layout_weight = "0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_oval_black"
            android:text="Invia"
            android:textSize="?attr/highContrastBeginText"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            />


    </LinearLayout>
```

And that's the code from this layout (it's a fragment )

```
public class ContactUsModalFragment extends BaseFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

protected Button sendEmailButton;
protected EditText editText;
protected String choice;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_us_fragment, container, false);
    getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

    TitleBar titleBar = view.findViewById(R.id.title_bar);
    titleBar.setRightButtonOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            BaseModalDialogFragment.dismissModal(getContext());
        }
    });

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_us_spinner);
    final ArrayList<String> choices = new ArrayList<>();
    choices.add("Sun");
    choices.add("Antares");
    choices.add("Alpha Centauri");
    choices.add("Tau Ceti");
    choices.add("Seleziona una categoria");

    /*ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(),R.layout.spinner_element_container,
            choices);*/


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),R.layout.spinner_element_container) {

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            if (position == getCount()) {
                ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText("");
                ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setHint(getItem(getCount())); //"Hint to be displayed"
            }

            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return super.getCount()-1; // you dont display last item. It is used as hint.
        }

    };

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter.addAll(choices);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setSelection(adapter.getCount()); //display hint
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {
            Object item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            if (item != null && position!=choices.size()-1) {
                choice = item.toString();
                }

            }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    sendEmailButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.ContactUsSendEmail);
    sendEmailButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.contactUsUserText);

    return view;
}
```

Basically when i use a device with a big screen the edittext will go up and the first line will show, when i use a smaller device the layout WILL go up but not enough and my edit text it's covered by the keyboard.
Suggestion?

[Edit Text covered by keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nt8J7.png)

[Normal layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lreNP.png)

Comment: If you can please share screenshot.

Comment: added two examples

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this in the android manifest file corresponding to the activity.

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize”> </activity>
```

** Your given layout code’s root is LinearLayout. This layout don’t find enough space to adjust your view and keyboard. Please make ScrollView as root and other layout elements inside of Scrollview.

Comment: Same result as the screenshot provided

Comment: Yes, i have just one main activity, the effect is what i've shown in the screenshot :S

Comment: In onCreateView you have set softInput to Adjust Pan programmatically. What’s reason behind that?

Comment: I'm trying many suggestion found here but none of them seems to work on a smaller screen.
I've even tried without it.
Was thinking of getting the dimension of the keyboard and move up the view

Comment: Your given xml code is for contact_us_layout fragment ?

Comment: that's right,i provided java and layout for the same page

Comment: Edited the answer. Please check

Comment: Ok, this works but it shrinks the regular view, might work a little bit on the layout to adjust it but it could be a good start!

Comment: Write it as <ScrollView <LinearLayout ... your content <LinearLayout/> <ScrollView/>

Comment: edited above, so the view do go up now but the default one is srhinked ,even with height and width set to match_parent.

Comment: Okay you are close to solution. Set your ScrollView height as wrap_content.

Comment: Thanks for the kidn replies!

Comment: I tried to upvote but i can't due to my status as new member

Comment: Okay no worries. You can accept this answer by clicking tick if you think you can solve your problem using these clues.